# How we can check null inside string.replace method?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

> I am using replace method to replace some text for example:-

```
let data = "My name is [[employeeName]]";

data.replace('[[employeeName]]', this.employee.employeeName);
```

Now my concern is the employee `object` which can be `null`, if it is `null` then above code will fail. So I want to put the condition some thing like this:

```
{this.employee ? this.employee.employeeName : ''}
```

**How can I put a condition inside the `replace()` method?**

Please assist me

Comment: Replace with `employeeName` or replace it with empty string?

Comment: data.replace('[[employeeName]]', (this.employee.employeeName==null)?'':this.employee.employeeName);

Comment: Uh, just place exactly what you wrote inside the `replace` argument?! `data.replace('[[employeeName]]', this.employee ? this.employee.employeeName : '');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(this.employee && this.employee.employeeName) || "";
```

i.e.

```
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', (this.employee && this.employee.employeeName) || "" );
```

**Note**

- This will replace `[[employeeName]]` with `""` when either of `this.employee` and `this.employee.employeeName` is `undefined`.

i.e., if your object is

```
var obj = {};
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', (obj.employee && obj.employee.employeeName) || "" ); //will still replace [[employeeName]] with ""
```

and

```
var obj = { employee : {} };
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', (obj.employee && obj.employee.employeeName) || "" ); //will still replace [[employeeName]] with ""
```

**But if `employeeName` is present**

```
var obj = { employee : { employeeName : "emp" } };
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', (obj.employee && obj.employee.employeeName) || "" ); //will replace [[employeeName]] with "emp"
```

Comment: Why not use the conditional operator as the OP had it in his question?

Comment: @Bergi OP's condition didn't handle `this.employee.employeeName` being undefined and handling it via conditional operator would have made the code longer, so I chose this approach.

Comment: Right, but I think his concern was only about `this.employee` being `null`, not about an existing employee having no name.

Comment: @Bergi In that case, replacement would have happened with `undefined` and I thought it wouldn't be a desirable scenario. I left a **note** as well explaining the consequence of using this solution to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to just add an 'OR' evaluation with a check that employee object is also not null :

```
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', this.employee ? this.employee.employeeName || "" : "");
```

Which will replace with empty string if employee is null, or employee name is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a ternary expression :

```
let name = this.employee? this.employee.employee.name: '';
let data = "My name is [[employeeName]]";
data.replace('[[employeeName]]', name);
```

or just put your code in an if else statement :

Also you don't actually need the replace function if you do so :

```
if(!(typeof employee ==="undefined")){
       let data= "My name is "+ this.employee.employeeName;
    }
    else{
      let data = "My name is nobody";
    }
```

Comment: inside the replace i want to apply the condition like this data.replace.('[[employeeName]]', {this.employee? this.employee.employeeName: ''});

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't. Code readability is important and by trying to put too much stuff in one single instruction you just make it harder to read without especially gaining anything back.